# filter out swear/curse words (abusive language) using an array

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

I’m making a nextcord bot and I want to implement a filter for swear/curse words. I want all those words in an array which is assigned to a variable (i.E. *badwords*). My problem is that it says "invalid syntax". Can you help me with this?

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    if "https://discord" in message.content:
        embed = nextcord.Embed(title="**Tu n'as pas le droit d'envoyer des liens d'invitation**")
        log = self.bot.get_channel(916007109424984115)
        logembed = nextcord.Embed(title="Link", description="Quelqu'un a envoyé un lien discord")
        await message.delete()
        await log.send(embed=logembed)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
    badwords = ["list of badwords"]
    elif badwords in message.content:
        log = self.bot.get_channel()
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

I didn’t do the embedding, neither the log-system for the swear/curse-words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to iterate over the elements of your list. This can be done this way:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    badwords = ["list of badwords"] #move list declaration over here
    if "https://discord" in message.content:
        embed = nextcord.Embed(title="**Tu n'as pas le droit d'envoyer des liens d'invitation**")
        log = self.bot.get_channel(916007109424984115)
        logembed = nextcord.Embed(title="Link", description="Quelqu'un a envoyé un lien discord")
        await message.delete()
        await log.send(embed=logembed)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        if any(badword in message.content for badword in badwords): # check if any badword in message.content 
            log = self.bot.get_channel()
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
            break # Exit the loop as we don't need to go further
```

Comment: For some reasons, the else: don’t work and it says invalid syyntax

Comment: I wrote the code on stackoverflow, maybe check the indentation ? Maybe adding the error to your comment could help more?

Comment: I checked it, and it seems fine to me. Did you tried the code before?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried without nextcord, it works fine

Comment: but does it works **with** nextcord? I’m using this api, not discord.py or pycord

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 mistakes in your code

you are iterating a list over your message.content and you are declaring badwords before your elif statement which is causing if statement to break, so declare it before start of if statement

```
message = 'curse'

badwords = ['curse'] #declare badwords here
if False:
    pass
elif message in badwords: # iterate your message.content over the badwords list
    print(True)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

is the invalid syntax caused by async def?
in that case you might want to check your python version is >3.6

Comment: i’m using repl.it, so my python is already updated. The async def needs to be there or i won’t be able to check messages from users